# CSS - How to make Mac OSX dock in CSS? Is there a third parameter other than height or width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos

How do you style this 3D transformed dock to have "depth" and not just have height and width?

[image]

(Notice at the rounded corner at the bottom, there's some grey "depth" around 3-5 pixels)

[image]

Here is how my CSS looks like right now:

```
.dock{
  transform: matrix3d(1,0,0.00,0,0.00,1,0.00,-0.0015,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1);
  width:800px;
  height:80px;  
  perspective: 300px;
  opacity:0.8;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:20px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(grey, white);
}
```

Much help would be appreciated!

**EDIT: Thanks so much for the help. Got this down in less than 5 minutes. Amazing!**

Comment: `box-shadow` or `filter: drop-shadow()`? (And by the way there are easier ways to do transforms than matrix 3d.)

Comment: http://zurb.com/playground/osx-dock

Comment: @gcampbell Care to share? :D Sadly in this way the dock becomes just for decoration since the contents get kinda transformed as well.

Comment: @makshh magic............ thanks!!!

Comment: The rounded corner is on both sides, but perspective makes it look less round in the back and more round in the front.

Comment: @myleschuahiock You could use `::before` for the dock background and apply the transform to the pseudo-element, which would leave the contents of the dock alone.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Wow... I never noticed that small minute detail.

Comment: @gcampbell Never knew that, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

`transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(45deg);` should do the job. You may want to change the values.

If you want to transform multiple nodes to the same vanishing point, you should read about the `perspective`-css-property.

Here is a good introduction on this topic: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/